# Delete my unintended SO [serverfault] tag?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, tags

I suspect that I totally goofed and too eagerly retagged [an SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21403914/1810429) with [[serverfault]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/serverfault/info) based on [too quick a read of MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47676/219145) following a comment on the question.

Upon noticing that the question was then the only one tagged [serverfault], I did [a bit more reading on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4128/219145)...and now suspect that I did something unholy: I subsequently dropped the [serverfault] tag that I added to the question.

(This just keeps getting messier I know....)  :/

What confuses me is that the [first round of MSO reading](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47676/219145) led me to believe that [serverfault] was an appropriate tag to use...and post-dates the [second round of MSO reading](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/4128/219145) that led me to think I resurrected a demon; but the second round of MSO reading included Jeff Attwood's rather unflattering thoughts on the tag (or maybe more specifically [belongs-on-serverfault] - same meaning I think, though).

(Yes, "confuses" is mild.  I am *totally confused* at this point!)  :}

Bottom line, the SO [[serverfault]](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/serverfault/info) tag I seem to have created(?) still exists but now has no questions tagged with it: should/would someone please delete it?

Comment: No, that tag is now orphaned and will be deleted with a script that runs at 03:00 UTC

Comment: Thanks, @rene - good to know.  Maybe someone can shed light on the other aspect of my question - whether using the tag was in fact unholy.  Also, I would love to understand the chronology of the related MSO Q&A I cited - where using these [<site>] tags has really landed.  I didn't find much to clarify in MSO's Q&A or help.

Comment: The tag you created is I guess a meta-tag. The posts you linked to are all related to meta.stackoverflow.com. All sites have their own meta site only meta.stackoverflow.com is different, it handles SO as well as stackexchange wide request. I assume the meta-tags existed for that purpose on meta.stackoverflow.com. I believe such tags shouldn't be used on stackoverflow.com. Use close votes, flags and/or comments for migration suggestions.